# Basic hello world stack manipulation troubles

Tags: c, static-analysis, stack, gcc, intel

I'm a beginner in reverse engineering, and as a beginner I started to read ["Reverse Engineering for beginers"](https://beginners.re/).
Here is the hello world program from the book (taken from chapter 3, page 12) :

> Now let’s try to compile the same C/C++ code in the GCC 4.4.1 compiler in Linux:
>   gcc 1.c -o 1 Next, with the assistance of the IDA disassembler, let’s see how
>   the main() function was created. IDA, like MSVC, uses Intel-syntax5.

```
main proc near

var_10 = dword ptr -10h

     push ebp
     mov ebp, esp
     and esp, 0FFFFFFF0h
     sub esp, 10h
     mov eax, offset aHelloWorld ; "hello, world\n"
     mov [esp+10h+var_10], eax
     call _printf
     mov eax, 0
     leave
     retn
main endp
```

There are two lines I don't understand at all :

- `and esp, 0FFFFFFF0h`
- `sub esp, 10h`

From what I understood from the book, we add `0FFFFFFF0h` (equals -16) value to ESP in order to align the stack to a 16byte boundary for optimisation.

My question is : why do we add -16 and then substract 16 to the stack? It seems pointless to me, can't we substract directly 32?
Second, if I'm understanding well:

- the program starts with EBP = ESP, because nothing is on the stack.
- Then EBP is pushed to the stack. Assuming the program is 64bit, ESP is now EBP - 8 (because of the 64bits). So now we have ESP != EBP.
- Then we copy the content of ESP into EBP. So we have EBP = ESP, and EBP = fristEBP (EBP when the program started) - 8.

Why do we need to modify the value of EBP? [PUSH instruction is supposed to change the value of ESP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4584089/what-is-the-function-of-the-push-pop-instructions-used-on-registers-in-x86-ass), not EBP, so why would there be any problem not modifying EBP value at the function prolog?

So now we have EBP = ESP, and both are fristEBP (EBP when the program started) - 8. So now we are adding -16 to the stack, so ESP becomes ESP - 16 (ESP - 24 if we consider that we've been adding -8 to the stack). 
What is -24 have to do with a 16byte boundary?
Why do we substract 16 again from the stack with `sub esp, 10h`?

Notes : I'm sorry for the english, and sorry if I'm asking dumb questions, the book isn't clear enought and I failed to find explainations on the net.

Comment: and not add aligns the stack to 16 byte boundary   ie 123456a1 & fffffff0 will result in 123456a0

Comment: Isn't there a risk of loosing data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not `add` in the first opcode. It's `and`. So it will clear the lower nibble for the last byte in the address. This is how the alignment is done and not by adding anything. Only later you `sub` 16 to have room for the local variables.

> Why do we need to modify the value of EBP?

We use `EBP` to store the initial `ESP` value. `EBP` is pointing to the current stack frame. This is the place for local variables created withing the function. Before we modify `EBP` it is stored on the stack so that we can restore it before we leave the function.

Comment: Okay I get it, but why add 0FFFFFFF0h and not 0FFFFFFF0F if we want to clear the lower nibble?

Comment: lower nibble are the bits `3-0` so why we would want to put 0 on bits `7-4` to do that?

Comment: I missread, sorry

Comment: ok, no worries!